# try and slingshot/try+ differences?

Tags: exception, clojure

I'm trying to write an exception handler for when `clj-http` returns 404. According to the Exceptions section in the [documentation](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http):

> clj-http will throw a Slingshot Stone that can be caught by a regular
>   (catch Exception e ...) or in Slingshot's try+ block

Trying this, it looks like there are some differences that I have trouble figuring out:

```
(ns my-app.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
  (:use [slingshot.slingshot]))

(try
  (client/get "http://some-site.com/broken")
  (catch Exception e (print "I found a problem!")))

=> I found a problem!
   nil

(try+
  (client/get "http://some-site.com/broken")
  (catch Exception e (print "I found a problem!")))

=> ExceptionInfo clj-http: status 404  clj-http.client/wrap-exceptions/fn--1604 (client.clj:147)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't filter for subclasses of `Exception`, that works fine:

```
(try+
  (client/get "http://some-site.com/broken")
  (catch Object _ (print "I found a problem!")))
```

The thing being thrown here is a native Clojure map with exception metadata, not traditional Java exception as such.

As such, if you're using Slingshot, you can filter on that map -- with fields such as request status, content returned, redirects, etc -- to have except blocks with much more fine-grained selection than just the class. For instance:

```
(try+
  (client/get "http://some-site.com/broken")
  (catch [:status 404] {:keys [trace-redirects]}
    (print "No longer exists! (redirected through " trace-redirects ")")))
```